# Python: dictionary and list manipulation help~

Tags: django, list, dictionary

I have an initialed dictionary list

```
list_dic = [{'number': 1}, {'number': 2}]
```

I also got a list of other objects, here just use int to represent

```
another_list = [2,3,4]
```

I want the result to be like this:

```
list_dic = [{'number': 1, 2: None, 3: None, 4: None},  \
{'number': 2, 2: None, 3: None, 4: None}]
```

Try use the least code to do so, thanks very much.

Comment: use the list as keys to create a default dictionary, and then update the old one.

Comment: Great! Please show the code for what you've done, and I'm sure somebody will be happy to help you improve it.

Comment: Alright, next time I'll post my code and ask for optimization instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You answered it yourself:

> use the list as keys to create a default dictionary, and then update the old one.

```
list_dic = [{'number': 1}, {'number': 2}]
another_list = [2,3,4]

for x in list_dic:
  x.update(dict.fromkeys(another_list))

print list_dic
```

Note how the for loop corresponds exactly with what you said; I think you just didn't know the correct names to use.  Usually the [docs](http://docs.python.org/) help in that case.

Comment: This is the way I did, but I probably want a better way to use [expression for in] syntax to improve it.

Comment: @user469652: What makes you think a list comprehension would, for this problem, be more Pythonic or better?

Answer (score 1):

Can't imagine why you'd want that, but here you go:

```
for dic in list_dic:
    dic.update(dict.fromkeys(another_list))
```

Comment: The main idea is learn more pythony way to code since I'm still new to python.

Comment: I think this is as Pythonic as it gets. You couldn't use a list comprehension, as `dict.update()` doesn't return the updated dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

```
[dic for dic in list_dic if dic.update(dict.fromkeys(another_list)) or True]
```